# Find: Field value is contained within given text

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a collection of `cars` and each car has a property `cars.make`. Let's say some of those cars have a `cars.make` value of `'Toyota'`. How do I find documents (using a MongoDB query) where the value `cars.make` is present in a given string, i.e. `'The Toyota Yaris was named car of the year in 2017.'`

Comment: Please share input data at jsoneditor online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, in PHP, because MongoDB Compass doesn't parse the JS-version of this filter and I'm lazy:

```
$results = $cars->find([
    '$expr' => [
        '$regexMatch' => [
            'input' => 'The Toyota Yaris was named car of the year in 2017.',
            'regex' => '$model',
            'options' => 'i' // case-insensitive
        ]
    ]
]);
```